# Animation doesn't work correctly while scrolling the website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with animation, when I scroll the page. You can see it above. 
Click "show notice" button and wait about 2 seconds, then the notice will start to hide.     Scroll up and down and you will see the notification is jumping up and down. What do I need to do to have notice always in the bottom of website window, even during scrolling?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sn1xfwxm/9/)

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="show notice">
<div id="notice"><p>Notice</p></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  height:3000px;
}

#notice {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  background:green;
  text-align:center;
  font:12px Verdana; color:white;
}

#notice p {
}
```

JS

```
function shownotice(){
    if(typeof(ntimeout)!='undefined')
        clearTimeout(ntimeout);
    $('#notice').css({'height':'0px', 'top':h+$(window).scrollTop()+'px'}).show().animate({'height':'+=40px', 'top':'-=40px'}, {duration:300});
    ntimeout=setTimeout(function(){hidenotice();}, 2000);
}

function hidenotice(){
    $('#notice').animate({'height':'-=40px', 'top':'+=40px'}, {duration:10600, complete:function(){$(this).hide();}});
}

$(function(){
    h=window.innerHeight||document.body.clientHeight;
    $('#notice').css({'top':h-$('#notice').height()+'px'});
    $('input').on('click', function(){shownotice();});
    $(window).scroll(function(){$('#notice').css({'top':h-$('#notice').height()+$(window).scrollTop()+'px'})});
});
```

Comment: I am not going to fix your code for you, but I wouldn't use `top`. Use `bottom` instead, have a play with that. Try it with `position:fixed;` too. [non-animated example](http://jsfiddle.net/f5yg2rvz/)

Comment: But in my code the notice is in the bottom of window, when it is not animated, too. There is only a problem with scrolling during the animation. Ok, I'll try with `position:fixed;`, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/sn1xfwxm/11/

changes to your original fiddle:

```
#notice {
    position:fixed;
```

removed the display: none, also!

the resulting js is much more simple:

```
$("#notice").hide(); //hide the notice on document load

$("#show").click(function () {
    $("#notice").stop(true, true).slideDown();
});
$("#hide").click(function () {
    $("#notice").stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
```